# GDB TUI Mode - Strange font when invoked from powerline shell

Tags: gdb, powerline

## **GDB** in **TUI-mode**

When I use gdb in tui-mode the command line show strange behaviour. Maybe the fonts of my powerline make problems.

- Has anybody a solution to this item?

[image: GDB in TUI Mode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The reason was a *.gdbinit* file, which colorize my gdb. However invoking gdb the following way solved the problem, but the colorize does not work now.

```
> gdb -n -tui filename
```